# ¿Porqué cuando creo una db en Firestore subiendo un archivo JSON el array lo muestra desordenado?

Tags: firebase, ordenamiento, firestore, index

:
Trabajando como principiante con Firebase, en Firestore he descubierto una forma de subir los archivos JSON sin crearlos manualmente ([introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWNiMQkW3u4)) y lo interesante que he observado es que la visualización de los mismos datos en pantalla de Firestore los entrega en forma desordenada, si bien está correcta la indexación de cada objeto del array porque lo he verificado y ni altera el sistema de consultas, en principio he creído que el ordenamiento de la los docs es con un criterio alfabético o de otro tipo al cuál ni lo logré entender o descubrir. dejo una captura de mi pequeña duda al respecto.
Tal vez mi consulta sobre una base de datos tan pequeña como la mía ni tiene relevancia y si tal vez si la db es gigante y lograr visualizar datos en la consola de Firestore va a ser todo un desafío en darle sentido a su orden desordenado.
Saludos y gracias de antemano!

[image: Subir JSON a Firebase]

Comment: En Firestore el nombre de un documento es de tipo cadena, por eso te va a colocar el `10` antes que el `2`. Si es importante para ti ese orden, nombra a los documentos poniendo ceros a la izquierda. Realmente tiene poca importancia, porque los datos de Firestore rara vez se consumen en la interfaz gráfica.

Comment: Excelente Cedano, gracias por la luz al tema, lo de poner un cero adelante entiendo que es improbable ya que esos números corresponden al índice del array que firestore lo convierte a cadena como bien lo mencionabas, yo subí un array de objetos , o tal vez usar la configuración en el json usado con un array de múltiples clave(número-cadena): valor(objeto) . De todos modos como bien dices pocas veces se usará la interfaz web. Saludos!

Comment: En Firestore es muy importante pensar en la forma en que consultarás los datos una vez guardados. Por ejemplo: ¿vas a necesitar en un futuro ordenar esos documentos por esos índices: 0,1,2,3 ...? Muchas veces eso condicionará incluso la forma en que deberás diseñar el modelo de datos teniendo en cuenta que Firebsse es No-SQL, y debes cuidar cosas como la cantidad de documentos o colecciones que se leen o se modifican. Un mal diseño puede llevar a situaciones catastróficas.